# Can't randomize cards. Some of them are duplicates

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, random, shuffle

I'm new to C, I am trying to randomize 16 cards. In the longer comments I wrote something that I don't have much clear... Btw this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define FACES 4
#define SUITS 4

void shuffle(char *wFace[], char *wSuit[], char *wMixed[][20]);     // prototype
size_t checker(char *wwMixed[][20], size_t current);                // prototype

int main(){
    char *face[] = {"Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    char *suit[] = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    char *mixed_cards[FACES*SUITS][20] = {0};           // initialize the final array

    shuffle(face,suit,mixed_cards);         // send to shuffle the pointer array

    for (size_t k=0; k<FACES*SUITS;++k){        // at the end
        printf("%s\n", *(mixed_cards+k));       // it prints the results
    }
}

void shuffle(char *wFace[], char *wSuit[], char *wMixed[][20]){

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (size_t j = 0; j<(FACES*SUITS); ++j){       // for every card
        do {
        size_t face = rand() % FACES;           // choose randomly
        size_t suit = rand() % SUITS;           // choose randomly
        sprintf(*(wMixed+j), "%s of %s", *(wFace+face), *(wSuit+suit));     // copy to *(wMixed+j) so in mixed_card[j][0] matrix
        } while (checker(wMixed, j));           // it does the cycle until checker function says that the string is unique
    }
}

size_t checker(char *wwMixed[][20], size_t current){
    for (size_t i=0; i<FACES*SUITS;++i){
        if ( (*(wwMixed+current) == *(wwMixed+i)) && (current!=i) ) {       // I don't get why I should use ONLY ONE *, since if I use only one it should be comparing ADDRESSES, NOT VALUES. if I put ** it doesn't work though, but I don't know why.
            return 1;           // the string is already in use, so it has to continue to randomize. it returns 1 and the while cycle continues so new rand string is created 
        }
    }
    return 0;                   // otherwise, if this for cycle doesn't find any duplicate, it returns 0 to shuffle function and while stops so j is increased (in the other for)
}
```

For example in line 38 I don't get why I should use ONLY ONE `*`, since if I use only one it should be comparing ADDRESSES, NOT VALUES. if I put `**` it doesn't work tough (loads indefinitely) so I left only one `*`, but I don't know why.
I think that the problem is somewhere inside checker (maybe this `**` thing).

One of the randomized outputs, as you can see, there are duplicates.c

```
Jack of Diamonds
Queen of Clubs
Ace of Hearts
Jack of Clubs
Ace of Diamonds
King of Diamonds
Ace of Spades
Jack of Spades
King of Spades
Jack of Clubs
Jack of Spades
King of Spades
King of Clubs
Queen of Hearts
King of Spades
King of Spades
```

Comment: make an array full of every possible value, shuffle the array (maybe [fischer-yates algorithm?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle))

Comment: @pmg how to deal with duplicates?

Comment: `mixed_cards` is currently a 2-D array of `char *`, but it looks like it should be a 2-D array of `char`: `char mixed_cards[FACES*SUITS][20] = {0};`. Then the `wMixed` (and `wwMixed`) function parameters should be declared as: `char wMixed[][20]` or `char (*wMixed)[20]` (same for `wwMixed`). You can use array indexing operations such as `sprintf(wMixed[j], "%s of %s", wFace[face], wSuit[suit]);`.

Comment: a common way to deal with playing cards is to "encode" `0` to `12` as 2 of Spades to Ace of Spades, "encode" `13` to `25` as 2 to Ace of Hearts, `26` to `38` as Clubs, and `39` to `51` as Diamonds (or thereabouts), so the sequence `0, 1, 2, ..., 51` has all 52 cards and no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You should first create the deck with every card without duplicates in the array:

```
void shuffle(const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[], char wMixed[][20]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i=0; i<FACES; ++i){
        for (size_t j=0; j<SUITS; ++j){
            sprintf(wMixed[i*SUITS+j], "%s of %s\n", *(wFace+i), *(wSuit+j));  // save the card string
            printf("%s", wMixed[i*SUITS+j]);   // print card string
        }
    }

    /*Add Fisher-Yates shuffle here*/

}
```

Then use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm to shuffle the array...

Answer (score 0):

Writing `(*(wwMixed+current) == *(wwMixed+i))` is essentially the same as writing:

```
(wwMixed[current] == wwMixed[i])
```

That is why you only need 1 `*`.

Since `wwMixed[i]` contains a string, and you want to compare strings, I suggest you use `strcmp()`:

```
if ( (strcmp(*(wwMixed+current),*(wwMixed+i)) == 0) && (current!=i) )
    return 1;
```

Comment: This fixed the issue!! But now I ask you, why before it didn't work and with strcmp works? Also, why **(wwMixed+current) is the same of *(wwMixed+current)?

Comment: @Mnkisd In C you need to use the function strcmp to compare strings, it isn't possible to compare arrays with comparison operators. And *(array+i) is the same as array[i], they are interchangeable, different ways to write the same thing.

Comment: @isrnick shouldn't **(wwMixed+current) get the value inside that array position? Isn't there another way to compare strings without using strcmp? Also, you wrote that             
*(array+i) is the same of array[i], but I asked about **(array+i) and *(array+i)

Comment: `**(array+i)` will give you the first character in the string `array[i]` (i.e. `array[i][0]`).  `*(array + i)` will give you the ith string in `array` (i.e. `array[i]`).

Comment: @Mnkisd to compare alphabetically you must use strcmp, or strncmp, or strcoll, or implement your own comparison of the characters in the array. And `**(array+i)` is not the same as `*(array+I)`, nowhere was it said they were.